# Adding a file content to model properties in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I try to add a custom property to a model which contains the result of file_get_contents(), but when I dump the model the property is not added.
Here is the model, I tried tu use th boot method in order to to populate the appended property but it doesn't work properly :

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Models;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DateTimeInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasManyThrough;
 
 
class Stage extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
 
    protected $table = 'stages';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_stages';
    protected $appends = ['pdf_file'];
 
  
    public function scopeDisplaySite($query)
    {
        return $query
            ->where('publish_catalog','=',1)
            ->where('status_stage','1');
    }
 
    /**
     * @param DateTimeInterface $date
     * @return string
     */
    protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date): string
    {
        return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
 
    
    public function distanciel():BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Stage::class,
            'stages_presentiel_distanciel',
            'id_stage_presentiel',
            'id_stage_distanciel');
    }
 
 
    public function setPdfFileAttribute()
    {

        $yearFolder = substr($this->n_stage,-3,2);
        $path = config('app.intranet_pdf_path').$yearFolder.'/'.$this->n_stage.'.pdf';
 
        //dd($this->n_stage);
 
        $handle = @fopen($path, 'r');
        if($handle){
            $this->pdf_file = file_get_contents($path);
        }else{
            $this->pdf_file = false;
        }
 
    }
 
    public function getPdfFileAttribute()
    {
        return $this->pdf_file;
    }
 
}
```

Just edited the code after your comments it does not appends the pdf_file property.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Laravel documentation:
`Note that attribute names are typically referenced using their "snake case" serialized representation`

Try:

```
protected $appends = ['pdf_file'];
```

Comment: ok, but how to populate this appended property automatically ?

Comment: @Eloise85 What do you mean ?  Once the attribute has been added to the appends list, it will always be included in both the model's array and JSON representations.

Comment: Just edited the code after your comments but it does not appends the pdf_file property when I dump the model.

Comment: can you `dd` the stage and show us the result ?

Comment: well pdf_file is added into your appends. You need to check the function for it's functionality. Does the code enters the `if` or `else` ?

Comment: It does not enter in the setPdfFileAtrribute, if I dd before if else it does not execute the dd...
Should I call the setter manually ?

Comment: Okay, that's another problem. Try to replace the content of set into the get method and retry it

Comment: The only way to make it working is to use the set method and calling it manually... Half satisfying.